# Tail sigma field

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have the following problem:

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of rv and $\tau = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} G_n$ Where $G_n= \sigma (X_n,X_{n+1},...)$.
The point of the exercise is to check if a certain event is in the tail $\sigma$-field.

I have the event:
$\{limsup S_k >0\}$ $S_k= \sum_{n=1}^k X_n$

I found the following example:

Tanking $\Omega = [0,1]$ U~unif(0,1) $X_1=U-1/2$, $X_n=0\forall n$
So:$\{limsup S_k >0\}$ =(1/2,1] which is not in the tail sigma field.

I'm not ok with the conclusion of this example since U-1/2 $\in[-1/2,1/2]$.. 
Does anyone know a formal proof?
I tried:

Define $E_k=\{S_n>0\}$
Then considering following...
$\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n} E_k$

I have: 
$E_k \in G_k$

$\bigcup_{k\geq n} E_k\in G_n$ 
And so $\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n} E_k \in G_1$

Which is clearly wrong some where.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can check that
$$[U\leqslant\tfrac12]=[\forall n,S_n\leqslant0],\qquad[U\gt\tfrac12]=[\forall n,S_n\gt0]=[\exists x\gt0,\forall n,S_n\geqslant x]
$$
hence
$$
[\limsup S_n\gt0]=[U\gt\tfrac12].
$$
In full generality, the random variable $\limsup S_n$ is not measurable with respect to the tail sigma-algebra of the sequence $(X_n)$.

Comment: Ah ok then I see now the argument of the example.. Could you say me something about my "proof"? Thank you